# 2D Array Checking Around Element

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm creating a small game and in order to generate a world, I need to add Room Objects to a World Object. My dilemma is that there needs to be a specific way of adding the Rooms, so that they all connect (i.e. no diagonals or "island" rooms). Picture below. (Ignore the colors, gray is empty space, colors are rooms)

[image: Ignore Colors]

What would be the best way of doing this? Currently I have something along the lines of

```
if (this.board[posx-1][posy].isOcc())
    valid == true;
if (this.board[posx][posy-1].isOcc())
    valid == true;
if (this.board[posx][posy+1].isOcc())
    valid == true;
if (this.board[posx+1][posy].isOcc())
    valid == true;
```

where if valid is true, it means that a Room is able to be placed there.
Where this becomes an issue is in the edges, where it goes out of bounds.

I have an initial base which will place one Room in a random column on the top row of the 2D Array, so there will always be something to build off of.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your "room" objects with references to their surrounding nodes for acceptable passage - i.e:

```
class Room {
    bool isTraversable = false;
    Room rooms = new Room[4]
}
```

Then, switch your map generator into being 2-pass, rather than just one. So, run your first generation (which may result in an invalid setup), then run a second pass over this which in short, checks if there's some sort of valid room to enter. If not, create a valid room.

So, a basic version of this would be;

```
hasValidPath = false;
foreach (Room r in rooms) {
    if (r.isTraversable) {
        hasValidPath = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!hasValidPath) {
    rooms[Mathf.Random(0,3)].isTraversable = true;
}
```

This would create a random traversable room where one of the connecting walls/blank areas are held. If you want to ensure you didn't just create "another island", run the same script over the newly traversable tile until a valid path is found.